# ESP-IDF (Espressif). Multiple IP addresses on one Ethernet or Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, esp32, esp-idf

In Windows/Linux, it is possible to configure multiple IP addresses on a network interface. I need to configure a Wi-Fi access point or Ethernet with a static IP and a DHCP server, but in a way that there are two IP addresses on ESP32 (two for Ethernet or two for Wi-Fi), for example: 192.168.4.1 and 192.168.4.2. How can I do that?

Let me explain why: one address (192.168.4.2) is used for data exchange between a program on the computer and the ESP32. The program can change the IP address using commands. Also, a web interface is used to configure the ESP32. Since the person doesn't know which address is currently assigned to the ESP32, I need a fixed second address (192.168.4.1) for accessing the web interface.

Here's my code for configuring Wi-Fi + DHCP-server:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "./sdkconfig.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include <esp_netif.h>
#include <esp_eth.h>

static const char *TAG = "eth_example";
esp_netif_t* esp_netif_ap=0;//Wi-Fi

static void wifi_event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                                    int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    if (event_id == WIFI_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED) {
        wifi_event_ap_staconnected_t* event = (wifi_event_ap_staconnected_t*) event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "station "MACSTR" join, AID=%d",
                 MAC2STR(event->mac), event->aid);
    } else if (event_id == WIFI_EVENT_AP_STADISCONNECTED) {
        wifi_event_ap_stadisconnected_t* event = (wifi_event_ap_stadisconnected_t*) event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "station "MACSTR" leave, AID=%d",
                 MAC2STR(event->mac), event->aid);
    }
}

void wifi_init_softap(void)
{
    esp_netif_ap=esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap();

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                        ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                        &wifi_event_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        NULL));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .ap = {
            .ssid = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID,
            .ssid_len = strlen(CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID),
            .channel = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_CHANNEL,
            .password = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_PASSWORD,
            .max_connection = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_MAX_STA_CONN,
            .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK
        },
    };
    if (strlen(CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_PASSWORD) == 0) {
        wifi_config.ap.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_OPEN;
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_AP));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_AP, &wifi_config));
    
    //stop DHCP
    esp_netif_dhcp_status_t DHCPStatus;
    esp_netif_dhcps_get_status(esp_netif_ap,&DHCPStatus);
    if (DHCPStatus!=ESP_NETIF_DHCP_STOPPED){
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_dhcps_stop(esp_netif_ap));
    }

    //Set static IP
    esp_netif_ip_info_t ip_info;
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.ip, 192, 168, 4, 1);
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.gw, 192, 168, 4, 1);
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.netmask, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_set_ip_info(esp_netif_ap, &ip_info));

    //Start DHCP
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_dhcps_start(esp_netif_ap));
    
    //Start Wi-Fi
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_softap finished. SSID:%s password:%s channel:%d",
             CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID, CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_PASSWORD, CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_CHANNEL);
             
}

void app_main() {
    //Initialize NVS
    esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
    if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
      ret = nvs_flash_init();
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);

    // Initialize TCP/IP network interface (should be called only once in application)
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    // Create default event loop that running in background
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());//цикл событий

    wifi_init_softap();//Wi-Fi
}
```

I tried to configure the second netif for Ethernet, it did not work, it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you an alternative for your use case, instead of assigning 2 IPs to the same interface.

To access the website, you could use mDNS to give it a local Domain name e.g. **esp-home.local**. Check out this [example and documentation from Espressif](https://github.com/espressif/esp-protocols/tree/master/components/mdns)
or to get a full implementation including mDNS, you can check [this example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/http_server/restful_server)

Comment: Here is a better [Espressif mDNS documentation link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-protocols/mdns/docs/latest/en/index.html)